# How to move a label in only one project

Tags: qgis-3

I see that if I use the "Move Label" button to adjust the location of a feature label in a map project, that will also move the location of that label in other map projects that I have created (using QGIS 3.4.11). Is there a way to move the label in one map project, but leave the label as is in other map projects?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your manual label placement is set up to use regular fields in the layer's attribute table. When you use the "move label" button, it edits the values in those fields. The X and Y fields are stored in the source data, so when you move a label in one project it will be moved in all projects that use the same fields.

That was how manual label placement worked in QGIS 2. In QGIS 3, label placement can be controlled by auxiliary fields. Auxiliary fields are stored in the project file rather than in the source data, so when you change the label placement in one project it doesn't affect the label placement in any other project.

So the best solution is probably to switch the data-defined label placement from regular fields to auxiliary storage fields. There's a good explanation in this blogpost: [Auxiliary Storage support in QGIS 3](http://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/17/auxiliary-storage-support-in-qgis-3/).

Another solution is to create new label placement fields, for this project only. This method would work best if you want to use the new label placement in multiple projects. Call the new fields something like "Label_X2" and Label_Y2". Use the Field Calculator to copy the values from the original fields into the new fields, then change the data-defined label placement setting to use the new fields. Now when you move the labels, the new fields will be edited instead of the old ones. In other projects that use the original fields, the label placement will stay the same.

Comment: Thanks csk! I'm not very good at this, so I'm still confused. The instruction says, "when the user select the map tool to move a label and click for the first time on the map, a simple question is asked allowing to select a primary key." That doesn't happen for me. Is that because I'm already set up for the old method? Do I need to do something to convert to the new method?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I see--I have to check the "Store data in the project" box under "Placement" in the "Labels" section of the Layers Properties.